# How to check if a cell is empty?

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for coding that checks if cell is empty or not. If it is not empty then move to the next cell group. But I need to check if the next cell group is empty or not. If not, then move to the next and so on.

My Current coding below.

```
If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("h3")) Then
    Do
    Checkbox1.Value = True
    Range("H3") = 17002
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I3") = Printerformat2.Text
Else
    Checkbox1.Value = True
    Range("l3") = 17002
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("m3") = Printerformat2.Text
End If
```

Comment: Might the cells have formulas?

Comment: That code can't possibly compile. `Do` without `Loop`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a for loop to iterate through the specified range in "H"

```
Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
  For i = 1 to 500

    If IsEmpty(.Range("h" & CStr(i)).Value) Then
     'Do 'Not sure where you're going with this one? This is not really needed from what I can tell.
     Checkbox1.Value = True
     .Range("H" & CStr(i)).Value = 17002
     Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & CStr(i)).Value = Printerformat2.Text
    Else
      Checkbox1.Value = True
      .Range("l" & CStr(i)) = 17002
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("m" & CStr(i)).value = Printerformat2.Text
    End If

   Next
End With
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: +1 but you're doing yourself a disservice by using string concatenation to build cell addresses.

Comment: What method would you suggest instead? I normally use "Cells" like so: `Private Enum Columns
    Employee = 1
    Department = 2
    Manager = 3
End Enum

Private Function getCellByString(column As Columns, row As Long) As String
    With Sheet1
       getCellByString = CStr(.Cells(row, column))
    End With
End Function

Public Sub GetDetails()
    MsgBox getCellByString(Manager, 2)
End Sub
`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at `Range("your range").specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`. This is the fastest way to loop through empty cells.
If you need to loop on non blank cells, you can check if your cell `Intersect` the empty cells range.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimized way to make sure a cell is not empty is "If Len(cell) <> 0".

You can use .offset to access another cell in relation to it's position from the current cell, or reference it directly, so you can check if it's empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 Application.WorksheetFunction.isblank(ActiveSheet.range("h3"))
```

instead of

```
 IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("h3"))
```

Cordially