# How to iterate through a variable-column-length range in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

For example, if the data in one worksheet looks like:
[image]

UsedRange.Columns.Count is 6 which is the maximum column count for all rows.
Even if I iterate using

```
For each row in UsedRange.Rows
       For each cell in row.Cells
           ...
       Next cell
Next row
```

It's still counting 6 for each row.

Comment: I want to iterate 6 times for Row 1 and 3 times for Row 2, etc. You see what I mean?

Comment: why do you want that? you can test for empty cell in your iteration in vba or you can use a `=count(1:1)` / `=counta(1:1)` formula for each row...

Comment: got it. thanks. I thought for each row there's a similar UsedColumn functionality that can wrap the empty test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just exit your cell loop if the cell is Empty.

```
For Each Row In UsedRange.Rows
   For Each cell In Row.Cells
       If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            Exit For
       End If

       'Do what you want here...

   Next cell
Next Row
```

Comment: The "If cell is empty then" line has "Runtime error '424' Object required." Changing it to "If IsEmpty(cell) then" works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`UsedRange` will return a jointed range. In your case, a small test:

```
Sub test()
Debug.Print UsedRange.Address
End Sub
```

prints `$A$1:$F$4`

So, you'd better check if there is any value in your cell before you execute your code.

See this SO thread: [How to check if a cell is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042571/how-to-check-if-a-cell-is-empty) to do so.